Replace only some words using a regular expression
I have a text with many "PROB TEMPO" and "TEMPO" words, and I want to insert a line break just before the word "PROB" or before the word "TEMPO" when PROB doesn´t appear before TEMPO.
I am using Python with re.sub
For example,
text = "PROB TEMPO BKN001 TEMPO BKN009 PROB TEMPO BKN008 TEMPO BKN012..."
new_text = re.sub("PROB TEMPO", "PROB </br>&emsp;TEMPO", text)
new_text = re.sub("BKN009 TEMPO", "BKN009 </br>&emsp;TEMPO", text)
new_text = re.sub("BKN012 TEMPO", "BKN012 </br>&emsp;TEMPO", text)

The problem is that I have to check all the possibilities. Could I use regular expressions in re.sub? For example, I used this but it didn´t work
new_text = re.sub("BKN0\d\d", "BKN0\d\d </br>&emsp;TEMPO", text)


It is not clear why you have that code attempt. It doesn't apply the logic that you have described. Instead it uses some logic that depends on the presence of BKNXXX words, which you have not used in the logic that you described at the top of your question. Are you assuming your text only has three types of words? PROB, TEMP, BKNXXX?

Also, that regex seems to suggest you never want to insert something at the very start of the input. Is that so? This is not mentioned in your description. Please provide several examples of inputs and the expected outputs for them.

None of the re.sub calls in the question add a newline before the PROB. Please [edit] the question to show more examples and also to show the wanted output.

Can you show exactly what the output should be for the given text because it looks like your implementation doesn't match your description. Also, if the tokens within the string are always separated by exactly one space character you could do this with a fairly simple loop rather than a complex RE

Try matching:
((?:\bPROB )?TEMPO\b)

and replacing:
\n\1

See: regex101
Python code see online python:
# import the re module
import re

s="PROB TEMPO BKN001 TEMPO BKN009 PROB TEMPO BKN008 TEMPO BKN012"

# match and substitution pattern
mPattern=r"((?:\bPROB )?TEMPO\b)"
sPattern=r"\n\1"

# substitution; notice thta `.lstrip()` removes the leading `\n`.
# dont know if thats desired. else just delete
res=re.sub(mPattern,sPattern,s).lstrip()

# result
print(res)

Outputs:
PROB TEMPO BKN001 
TEMPO BKN009 
PROB TEMPO BKN008 
TEMPO BKN012


Explanation
match:

(): capture to group 1
(?:\bPROB )?: maybe preceeded with word PROB 
TEMPO\b: the word TEMPO

replace:

\n\1: linebreak and matched


There are two ways to solve your problem.
One is to simply substitute both patterns "PROB" and "TEMPO" (not preceded by "PROB") in turn:
import re

text = "PROB TEMPO BKN001 TEMPO BKN009 PROB TEMPO BKN008 TEMPO BKN012..."

new_text = re.sub(r"PROB", r"<br/>&emsp;PROB", text)
new_text = re.sub(r"(?<!PROB) TEMPO", r"<br/>&emsp;TEMPO", new_text)
print(new_text)

Will print:
<br/>&emsp;PROB TEMPO BKN001<br/>&emsp;TEMPO BKN009 <br/>&emsp;PROB TEMPO BKN008<br/>&emsp;TEMPO BKN012...

The (?<!PROB) part is a negative lookbehind as explained in the documentation and will match something not preceded by "PROB".
The other solution uses two more regex tools: the or operator and backreferences and is a bit more elegant from the regex point of view.
import re

text = "PROB TEMPO BKN001 TEMPO BKN009 PROB TEMPO BKN008 TEMPO BKN012..."

new_text = re.sub(r"PROB|(?<!PROB) TEMPO", r"<br/>&emsp;\g<0>", text)
print(new_text)

Will print:
<br/>&emsp;PROB TEMPO BKN001<br/>&emsp; TEMPO BKN009 <br/>&emsp;PROB TEMPO BKN008<br/>&emsp; TEMPO BKN012...

The pattern to match is "PROB" OR "TEMPO" (not preceded by "PROB").
The \g<0> in the replacement string is a backreference to the entire match.
In your question, you attempted to use a backreference with started your replacement string with BKN0\d\d.
The intention is obvious but this will only resolve to literal backspace-d's.
Backreferences tell the regex engine "that's what a previous pattern matched".
Also note that I used <br/> (not </br>) as this is the correct XHTML element for a line break.
This assumes your string is somehow used in an HTML document.
Wiktor's answer demonstrates how to add actual line breaks.

Probably because answering in a half a minute, looks like you used ChatGPT and they didn't realize you have seen this question in SG beforehand.

@gre_gor sounds convincing. Thank you for the insight. I was actually thinking about this question for the better part of the last day. I was reluctant to approve it but then people started hinting at a solution without giving it which IMHO is just cruel.

My guess is that downvotes reflect that this doesn't produce the expected output.

Also, there were things mentioned in the SG that the asker had not resolved, and so now we have a question that is underspecified. This could have been prevented if this question was retained in SG until asker had improved their question. That's what it is for.

@trincot thank you for being so frank. No disrespect intended but I found your comments on SG to miss the point. I agree the lack of expected output is a problem. Why didn't you ask for it? I saw the SG going nowhere with people hinting at (flawed) solutions and no new constructive criticism coming forth.

I didn't hint at a solution, and my comments there were sincere questions on lacking specifications. If you thought of missing examples, why do you put the burden on me to ask for them? If you found something lacking in the comments that I or others made, aren't you free to add to those comments? I don't feel that just moving it out of SG is the right decision to cope with that.

@trincot no, you didn't hint at solutions. I didn't mean to say you did. When I approved the question, I thought it was understandable what OP wanted - even without expected output.

Those "hints" btw triggered me to finally do this.

You can use
import re

text = "PROB TEMPO BKN001 TEMPO BKN009 PROB TEMPO BKN008 TEMPO BKN012..."
print( re.sub(r"\b(?!^)(PROB\s+TEMPO|(?<!PROB\s)TEMPO)\b\s*", "\n\\g<0>", text) )

See the Python demo and the regex demo. Output:
PROB TEMPO BKN001 
TEMPO BKN009 
PROB TEMPO BKN008 
TEMPO BKN012...

The \b(?!^)(PROB\s+TEMPO|(?<!PROB\s)TEMPO)\b\s* regex matches any PROB TEMPO or TEMPO (not immediately preceded with PROB and a whitespace) a whole words.
If you need to support more than one whitespace before TEMPO, you'd need to intall PyPi regex module and then import regex as re and use \b(?!^)(PROB\s+TEMPO|(?<!PROB\s+)TEMPO)\b\s*.

The OP talks about inserting "line break" but the code implies that what's needed is an HTML line break (br) followed by an em space

@SIGHUP It is not a big deal replacing \n with whatever ones needs. A newline is a concept, the final implementation should use whatever they define as a "newline".

Although OP is asking about how to use RE for this it's not clear if RE is actually a requirement. Why not use a simple loop?
text = "PROB TEMPO BKN001 TEMPO BKN009 PROB TEMPO BKN008 TEMPO BKN012"

p, *tokens = text.split()

result = p

for t in tokens:
    if t == "PROB" or (t == "TEMPO" and p != "PROB"):
        result += r"<\br>&emsp;"
    else:
        result += " "
    result += (p := t)

print(result)

Output:
PROB TEMPO BKN001<\br>&emsp;TEMPO BKN009<\br>&emsp;PROB TEMPO BKN008<\br>&emsp;TEMPO BKN012

Note:
Although not specifically stated in the OP, my guess is that br would not be required at the start of the output string.
This implementation for the relatively small input string is significantly faster than a RE solution
